# how to take fullpage screenshot using playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm new to browser automation

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a full webpage (example: https://www.apple.com/) using the below code

```
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1200, "height": 500})
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.apple.com")

    
    # Wait for the page to load completely
    page.wait_for_load_state("load")

    # Scroll to the bottom of the page to load additional content
    # page.evaluate("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(5)

    # Capture a screenshot of the entire page
    page.screenshot(full_page=True, path="full_page_screenshot1.png")

    browser.close()
```

I am getting output like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1euM7.jpg

But my output should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTCeH.png

Comment: Why do you want a bunch of empty space on the right? That's not part of the website.

Comment: @ggorlen white space is not required I just resized it for uploading here.

Comment: Oh, got it, I see the second one is longer and images haven't loaded. You may need to scroll down.

Comment: `for i in range(numSteps):
        page.evaluate(f'(scrollIncrement) => {{ window.scrollBy(0, scrollIncrement); }}', scrollIncrement)
        time.sleep(delayBetweenSteps)`

@ggorlen I used the above loop to scroll down and now I can capture the image, thank you

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).